# How to understand objects, methods and arguments in Ruby calculations

Tags: ruby

While learning Ruby gotchas, I am getting different results with some calculations in IRB:

```
1-2-7-2 # => -10

1.-2.-7.-2 # => 4

1.-2.-7.-2.-4 # => 8

1.-2.-7.-2.+4 # => 0

1.-(2).-(7).-(2) # => -10
```

Possibly it is related to methods and arguments? I am trying to wrap my head around this.

Comment: I think if you follow the explanation in the [Ruby style guide](https://github.com/rubocop-hq/ruby-style-guide#method-invocation-parentheses), you can avoid these problems.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've chosen an interesting way to approach calculations.

I guess you are trying to omit zeros in your expression `1.-2.-7.-2` which will return `-10` if you write it as `1.0 - 2.0 - 7.0 - 2`.

The way you're getting `4` is because `1.-` construction calls `-()` method because everything is an object in Ruby and then you pass an argument to the function.

In your case it will be parsed as

```rb
1.-( 2.-( 7.-(2) ) )

# if we try to unwrap
a = 7.-(2) # => 5
b = 2.-(a) # => -3
1.-(-3) # (or 1 + 3) => 4
```

Comment: Ah yes, I forget about object encapsulation. Thank you :)

Comment: Good answer that could be improved by removing the oft-heard falsehood “ because everything is an object in Ruby ”. (Variables and blocks, for example, are not objects.)